# Validar si los datos son nulos

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode

Como puedo validar si un URL de mi base de datos es NULL y si es así muestre una alerta pero si si tiene URL lo abra

```
func Facebook(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: face){
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Aviso!!!", message: "Mmmm, no     tengo url!", delegate: nil,
                                cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

De esta forma obtengo los datos

```
values = ((try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,  options: .AllowFragments)) as? NSArray)!<br/>

face = values[indexPath.row]["facebook"] as! String
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿la *URL* es null o el *contenido* de la URL es null?

Comment: el contenido de la tabla es null

Answer (score 1):

tu código quedaría así:

```
>         func Facebook(sender: AnyObject) {
          var url= NSURL(string: face)
>         if url != nil{ 
>             UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
>         }else{
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Aviso!!!", message: "Mmmm, no tengo url!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

>     }
```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)

Comment: Me aparece un error con el url:string?
Cannot convert value of type "NSURL?" to specified type String?

Comment: Ys esta, si no recibe nada, estara en null asi que no entrará en el if sino en else

Comment: En el if url, siempre me pone que inserte es un diferente o igual a nil

Answer (score 1):

Con esto puedes llamar una url, si no se puede crear la NSURL no se ejecuta y lanza un mensaje

```
func CallFacebook(face: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: face){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Aviso!!!", message: "Mmmm, no tengo url!", delegate: nil,
                                cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Edito la pregunta para que veas como obtengo los datos de la BD

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta ;)

Comment: Fijate como se usa if let url = NSURL(string: face) que ademas de la asignacion pues valida el valor de url..